# Is there a way to stop a script execution on Node.js using Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices?

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, cancellation

I am trying to execute some javascript on Node server, using Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices, with this code:

```
JObject result = null;
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = tokenSource.Token;
var scriptTimeout = 2000;

tokenSource.CancelAfter((int) scriptTimeout);

result = await _nodeServices.InvokeExportAsync<JObject>(token, "./Node/script", "run");
```

The InvokeExportAsync in fact provides a CancellationToken parameter that successfully kills the task, but the node process keeps consuming CPU until the script finishes.

For example, if I try to run a script that takes 10m to complete and the cancellation token kills it on 5m, I can see for more 5m the script executing and consuming CPU on task manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should never try to terminate the node process when some task is canceled .**

The `CancellationToken` parameter in `InvokeAsync<T>(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string moduleName, params object[] args)` is not used to terminate the `Node.js` process , **but used to cancel the `.NET` code that invokes those scripts written in `Node.js`** .

Let's say there're 3 async tasks running in Node.js:

```
setTimeout(resolve, 100, 100); // task 1
setTimeout(resolve, 200, 100); // task 2
setTimeout(resolve, 300, 100); // task 3
```

Now we want to cancel the 2nd task , since `INodeServices` is an singleton service, and JavaScript runs in single thread, if we choose to terminate the node.js process, task 1 and task 2 will also fail .

Secondly , **`.NET` has no idea about what should be done in `Node.js` when a task reaches its timeout limit**. Let's say you've asked for some resources in `Node.js` , and you'll free the resources when task is completed. Now you're using the `.NET` to cancel the task, what about the resources allocated in `Node.js` ?

I suggest you should wrap your `Node.js` code into an auto cancelable task. Because JavaScript has no cancelable promise yet, you might use a 3rd party lib or custom your own addons.